# Установка платформ. Android. Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcreator

При установке не устанавливаются автоматически платформы. При создании проекта высвечивается только комплект MinGW 32bit. Вопрос: как же добавить комплекты для Android? В параметрах в пункте "Сборка и запуск"  я не очень понял, как это сделать.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Нужно:

- установленный NDK
- установленный Qt для Android (http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.5/5.5.0/qt-opensource-windows-x86-android-5.5.0.exe)

У меня нет под рукой установки с NDK и Qt, но там делается всё однотипно.

1. Отркываем Параметры
2. Идём на пункт Build & Run (Сборка и запуск)
3. Переходим на вкладку Compillers (Компиляторы)
4. Жмём кнопку Add -> GCC, после чего вводим:

   - Имя: произвольно, пусть будет Android NDK
   - Compiler path: указываем ПОЛНЫЙ путь к компилятору C++ из NDK. Компиляторов там несколько: что по версиям, что по платформам.
   - ABI: там вариантов немного должно быть, выбираем подходящий
5. Жмём Apply
6. Идём на вкладку Qt Versions
7. Жмём Add и выбираем qmake.exe нужной версии Qt. Так же и как и компиляторы оно может быть под несколько платформ - выберите нужное. Задаём имя, пусть будет Android Qt
8. Жмём Apply
9. Идём на вкладку Kits
10. Жмём Add и даём подобные параметры:

    - Name: Android NDK
    - Device type: Android Device
    - Device: выбираем ваше андроид устройство которое вы настраивали на вкладке, что у вас на скриншоте
    - Compiler: выбираем созданный нами компиллер на этапе 4.
    - Qt Version: выбираем созданный нами профиль для Qt на этапе 7.

Собственно и всё. Хотя, судя по сообщению ошибки, вы всё правильно сделали, но вам нужно добавить только профили для Qt Version (шаги 6-7) для Qt x86/arm/mips. После чего Kits (Комплекты) могут сгенерироваться сами из того диалога, что у вас на экране.